# Does reformatting an NTFS drive to EXT4 remove the fragmented parts of it?

Tags: server, ntfs, ext4

I purchased a 2TB hard drive that was initially formated as ntfs and have been using it on my NAS for a while. I did a scan on it and found out it was a bit fragmented. I didn't want to waste time defragmenting it so I just formated the whole thing to EXT4 on my nas since all the other drives are EXT4 on it. I was wondering if it also fixes the need to defrag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragmentation is when a file is divided into several pieces among the disk. It's not an issue with the drive itself, but in the data that lies there. Because the problem isn't in the disk but in the files, the fragmentation goes away when the files go away (which happens as you format to ext4). Fragmentation is also not an issue in ext4 until you run out of space on the drive as ext4 is capable of filling up the drive smarter than just starting at one end filling it up from there. It is a known issue with Windows that its file system is lagging behind the times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is no need to defragment files on a drive without files. Simple questions don't require long answers.